# issue with update in mongoose 3.10.8

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to update a collection using Mongoose 3.10.8

```
let findQuery = {username: data.username};

 let updateQuery ={
    "$addToSet":{
                "schemes":{
                    "$each":[data.schemes]
                }
            }
    };


 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.modelInstance.update(findQuery, updateQuery).exec((err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    })
```

But my code triggers the following error:

> { MongoError: '$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {: ...}}

If I enable debug mode with `mongoose.set('debug',true)`, I see that there is an empty `$set` in the query.

```js
Mongoose: studentnotifications.update(
  { username: 'username1' },
  {
     '$set': {},
     '$setOnInsert': {
         created_at: new Date("Fri, 15 Sep 2017 12:51:36 GMT")
     }, '$addToSet': {
         schemes: {
             '$each': [ { schemeName: 'scheme1' } ]
         }
     }
  },
  { overwrite: undefined }
)
```

Then am I supposed to disable set?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after reading the following document

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.8-Release-Notes#modelupdate-now-supports-overwrite

I had to set an option {overwrite:true}

But how do I disable to the updatedAt: new Date("Fri, 15 Sep 2017 13:02:28 GMT"), created_at: new Date("Fri, 15 Sep 2017 13:02:28 GMT")

Because I am getting the error

```
{ MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not valid for storage.
```

If I remove the updatedAt field the data is getting updated while running it in the command prompt